# Change left margin for long equations

Tags: equations, margins

Lets say I have a long aligned equation with a `overfull \hbox` of `20pt` and I want to reduce the left margin of `10pt` so to have and `overfull \hbox` of only `10pt`. How can I get this without adding a negative space to each line?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
My ``overfull {\textbackslash}hbox'' long equation example
\begin{align}
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried with the `adjustwidth` ambient of the `changepage` package but it, sometimes, doesn't work (and I can't understand why).

**NOTE1.** I need a solution that works with very long, **multy-page** "aligned" equations. I can't split them.

**NOTE2.** I DO NOT need to resize the equation. I know I can do it, but sometimes I just need to change the left margin.

Comment: But why don't you use `multlined`, `split` or `aligned` for the part of the lines that would go into the margin?

Comment: @Bernard because, in some cases, the only thing I really need is to change the left margin.

Answer (score 1):

Package `changepage` works as advertised :). However, it can't start on one page and stop on next!

Try the following MWE (as `changepage` is used, it works ...) change oitside margin :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
My ``overfull \verb+\hbox+ long equation example
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\marginparwidth}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In case that you like to change left, i.e. inside, margin, for example extend for 22mm, thant this is accomplish with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
My ``overfull \verb+\hbox+ long equation example
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{-22mm}{}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x   \\
& x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If bot examples don't work in your document, than you have in it some mismatch not shoved in your MWE.

Comment: I add new example and images of resulted document. Please, let me know is any of both examples fulfill your expectation and if not, what I miss in your question.

Comment: As I stated, I've already tried the changepage solution. You said that it can't start on one page and stop on the next. In my test this seems not true. Your solutions are good but in some cases (I can't share with you because are copyrighted material) it does not work. But I really thank you for the `showframe` package tip. ;-)

Comment: I have reach experience with `changepage` package and It always work. To convince me, that I'm wrong, please provide MWE, where it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your equations contain lots of `+` and/or `-` symbols, you may to consider reducing the value of the length parameter `\medmuskip`. For instance, issuing the instruction `\medmuskip=2mu` lets the `align` environment fit comfortably.

The full MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe}
\begin{document}
\begingroup % localize scope of next instruction
\medmuskip=2mu % <-- new
\begin{align}
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\notag\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x
\end{align}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I stated in the note, I know I can do that. I really need to change the left margin.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - You'd written that you know how to *resize* equation material. Changing the value of `\medmuskip` is unrelated to resizing the equation material.

Comment: I really appreciate each attempt to help. For me changing the value of `\medmuskip` is related to resize the equation material because it resizes the binary operators space. I think the example I used is a little misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough, even without making computations.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
My \verb|Overfull \hbox| long equation example
and some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text
\begin{equation}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
$\begin{aligned}
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x
\end{aligned}$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I see you're using `\pdfoutput=1`. Don't. Compile with `pdflatex`.

If you want to break displays, you can do it as well, with `changepage` (but it requires computations); also the equation numbers will be shifted, of course.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,changepage}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
My \verb|Overfull \hbox| long equation example
and some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text
\begin{adjustwidth}{-10pt}{-10pt}
\begin{align}
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
&x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x
\end{align}
\end{adjustwidth}
My \verb|Overfull \hbox| long equation example
and some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice and useful solution. I'll use it for sure. But I need also a solution that works with multy-pages aligned equations.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Changing the margin for multipage displays is something I'd never consider. Splitting the equations is the way to go.

Comment: Dear "Figaro", I'm only a poor Almaviva and I'm really not allowed to do what I want... ;-) Now I'm dealing with a ten page aligned equation... I have a 12 pt overfull and I'd prefer non resizing with the `\small` command (but I'll do if I don't find something "quick and painless").